# Iframe working correctly on localserver but not production server

Tags: django, iframe, dev-to-production

A question like this was asked before and the person got nothing but criticisms, hope this won't be the case here.

I have a website that allows a business to add their menu to my site, and some have requested to be able to import a menu (a pdf or jpg) that is already online elsewhere. So I made a form that saves a url to the db and then that url is used in the src of an iframe on my site.

I tested it all and it worked fine on my local machine (using Django development server). When I synced it over to my production server and saved the same url I was testing with, the iframe loads no content.

I imagine that it has something to do with trying to read an individual file from another server because it works if I make the url google.com or to an image that is under my domain name. Is there anything I can do to fix this? Storing a url instead of a pdf in my db is much more efficient so doing this way is preferred over uploading their menu to my site.

I don't think this question needs any code attached, but if you want to see some let me hear it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The menu you're testing with probably has the [`X-Frame-Options`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/The_X-FRAME-OPTIONS_response_header) response header set.

Is there a reason you're putting the image/pdf as the `src` on an `iframe` instead of just using the `img` tag (or putting an `img` tag inside your `iframe`)?  There's still no guarantee that will work for all pages, as some sites will refuse to serve media to an external page, but I suspect this is your problem in this case.